# Pandas transform to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I've been given some dates in an strange format and I don't manage to read them as datetime pandas format.

An example would be: `736698.0`, which should be `'2017-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'`. So, it seems the original format is days since 1/1/1BC (as first day of year zero, but there's no such year, so it's year -1).

I have tried to use `pandas.to_datetime(736698.0, unit='D', origin=datetime.datetime(1/1/0))` and other combinations, but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Are you sure the expected date is 2017 and not 2018?

Comment: As you can't create a date with negative year or 0, maybe you can use `datetime(1, 1, 1)  + timedelta(days=736698) - timedelta(days=366)`. The output will be `datetime(2017, 1, 4, 0, 0)`

Comment: @Pep_8_Guardiola I'm sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy` to do that as it supports ['BC' years](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units):

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.datetime64('000') + np.timedelta64(736698, 'D')
numpy.datetime64('2017-01-04')
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [736698.0]})

df['Date2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'], unit='D').to_numpy() + np.datetime64('000')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Date      Date2
0  736698.0 2017-01-04
```

Comment: This does it. Year '000' is how numpy calls year 1BC, and it takes into account that is 366 days long. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the given floats into a datetime with the following. As we cannot set a `year=0`, we must subtract that from the final result:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date_num'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(x) - datetime.timedelta(366))

# Output
# Date_num  Date
# 736698.0  2017-01-04
```

Comment: Good answer, but the timedelta should be 366 days

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that, edited

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vectorial method and expect the final dates to be recent, you can subtract a valid epoch:

```
# use a valid origin
epoch = pd.to_datetime('1970-1-1')
# define the value of this origin relative to your reference
epoch_from_ref = 719527

# perform the conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].sub(epoch_from_ref),
                            unit='D', origin=epoch)
```

Output:

```
      col       date
0  736698 2017-01-05
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [736698]})
```

Comment: Good answer, but epoch_from_ref should be 719527. But how did you calculate it?

Comment: @geofisue I did it manually from the date you provided. You could use `epoch_from_ref = 736698 - (pd.to_datetime('2017-01-04')-pd.to_datetime(epoch)).days - 1`.